# Unable to connect Share Point site in Power Apps Canvas app

Tags: list, canvas, sharepoint, gallery, powerapps

I have a SharePoint list named "Project Tracker" and this list has some records. Now, I want to connect this list to my Power Apps [Blank Canvas app -> Connect Data]. Unfortunately, I am facing an error [The data did not load correctly. Please try again]. I am trying a couple of times, but it is not resolved.
[image]

Please, suggest any solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an incident at Microsoft. You can check the status on the [Microsoft 365 Health Dashboard](https://admin.microsoft.com/).

> Title: Users can't access Microsoft Power Apps
>
> User impact: Users may be unable to access Microsoft Power Apps.
>
> Current status: Our initial efforts to revert the TLS configuration
> change were unsuccessful, however we’re reimaging the affected
> machines in order to roll back successfully. We’re continuing to
> monitor the service health to confirm these actions are successful.

[image: power apps issue]